# Qt execute external executable program?

Tags: android, qt

I am writing a `Qt` program to connect with `Android` devices.

I know that I should execute the `adb` first, and the connection is based on `TCP`, so I need to run

```
./adb forward tcp:xxport tcp:xxport
```

How to run this line in `Qt` ? I have copy the `adb` to my project file.

I develop this on `Linux`, and would run on `Windows XP` , so prefer cross-platform plan (only works on `Windows XP` is fine also).

Answer (score 0):

```
QProcess p;
p.start(adbBinaryPath(), {"forward", "tcp:xxport", "tcp:xxport"});
```

To run adb you can use QProcess. Note that you need compiled adb binary for each windows and linux platforms.